# Integer Counter when value in next row changes

Tags: pandas, cumsum

I'm having a problem adding a "counter column" in my dataframe.

I parsed values from multiple columns into so called "merged_attributes" and now I want to create a counter that increments by 1 when value of "merged attributes" columns changes.

I have below dataframe, last column is desired column:

```
   Price  UNIQUE  MERGED_ATRIBUTE  COUNTER
0  52.08       1           52.081        1
1  52.08       1           52.081        1
2  52.20       1           52.210        2
3  52.20       1           52.210        2
4  52.20       1           52.210        2
5  52.20       1           52.210        2
6  52.20       1           52.210        2
7  52.20       1           52.210        2
8  70.10       1           70.110        3
```

How do I achieve this?

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or with `cumsum()` and equality check with previous row:

```
c = df['MERGED_ATRIBUTE']
df['COUNTER'] = c.ne(c.shift()).cumsum()
```

---

```
   Price  UNIQUE  MERGED_ATRIBUTE  COUNTER
0  52.08       1           52.081        1
1  52.08       1           52.081        1
2  52.20       1           52.210        2
3  52.20       1           52.210        2
4  52.20       1           52.210        2
5  52.20       1           52.210        2
6  52.20       1           52.210        2
7  52.20       1           52.210        2
8  70.10       1           70.110        3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```py
df['COUNTER'] = df.groupby('MERGED_ATRIBUTE').ngroup() + 1
```

This creates a group for each value of `MERGED_ATRIBUTE` and then uses [GroupBy.ngroup](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html):

> Number each group from 0 to the number of groups - 1.

This returns the following DataFrame:

```
   Price  UNIQUE  MERGED_ATRIBUTE  COUNTER
0  52.08       1           52.081        1
1  52.08       1           52.081        1
2  52.20       1           52.210        2
3  52.20       1           52.210        2
4  52.20       1           52.210        2
5  52.20       1           52.210        2
6  52.20       1           52.210        2
7  52.20       1           52.210        2
8  70.10       1           70.110        3
```

Note that this attributes a unique number to each attribute, so this answer differs from that of @sophocles if the `MERGED_ATRIBUTE` is not sorted:

```
>>> df2
   Price  UNIQUE  MERGED_ATRIBUTE
0  52.08       1           52.081
1  70.10       1           70.110
2  52.08       1           52.081
>>> df2.groupby('MERGED_ATRIBUTE').ngroup() + 1
0    1
1    2
2    1
dtype: int64
>>> df2['MERGED_ATRIBUTE'].ne(df2['MERGED_ATRIBUTE'].shift()).cumsum()
0    1
1    2
2    3
Name: MERGED_ATRIBUTE, dtype: int64
```